# illegal instruction (core dumped) message when displaying generated image using numpy and matplotlib

Tags: python, numpy, image-processing, matplotlib, scipy

When running the following code segment, the last two lines of code `plt.imshow(X[0,:,:])   plt.show()`  keep generating the error message of `Illegal instruction (core dumped)`  The X shape is `(1, 572, 572)`. May I know what can be the reason of this?

```
import os
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pylab
from scipy.ndimage.filters import gaussian_filter
from scipy import ndimage

np.random.seed(1234)
pylab.rcParams['figure.figsize'] = (10.0, 8.0)

nx = 572
ny = 572
sigma = 10

plateau_min = -2
plateau_max = 2

r_min = 1
r_max = 200

def create_image_and_label(nx,ny):
  x = np.int(np.random.rand(1)[0]*nx)
  y = np.int(np.random.rand(1)[0]*ny)

  image = np.ones((nx,ny))
  label = np.ones((nx,ny))
  image[x,y] = 0
  image_distance = ndimage.morphology.distance_transform_edt(image)

  r = np.random.rand(1)[0]*(r_max-r_min)+r_min
  plateau = np.random.rand(1)[0]*(plateau_max-plateau_min)+plateau_min

  label[image_distance <= r] = 0 
  label[image_distance > r] = 1
  label = (1 - label)

  image_distance[image_distance <= r] = 0 
  image_distance[image_distance > r] = 1
  image_distance = (1 - image_distance)*plateau

  image = image_distance + np.random.randn(nx,ny)/sigma

  return image, label[92:nx-92,92:nx-92]

def create_batch(nx,ny,n_image):

  X = np.zeros((n_image,nx,ny))
  Y = np.zeros((n_image,nx-184,ny-184,2))

  for i in range(n_image):
     X[i,:,:],Y[i,:,:,1] = create_image_and_label(nx,ny)
     Y[i,:,:,0] = 1-Y[i,:,:,1]

  return X,Y

X,Y = create_batch(nx,ny,1)

print(X.shape)
plt.imshow(X[0,:,:])
plt.show()
```

Comment: This sounds like a bug in matplotlib. Have you considered submitting a report to their mailing list (per http://matplotlib.org/faq/troubleshooting_faq.html)?

Comment: This can be caused by a "corrupt" binary .so file, typically if someone has taken a text editor to the file, or if it is the wrong architecture.

Comment: It could be related to this issue: https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=215589. The solution (uninstalling atlas-lapack-base and installing lapack) worked for me when I was getting the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Works fine for me.  Try upgrading and/or reinstalling your libraries and/or Python.

If it still fails, consider using `gdb` to get a stack trace (hint: `gdb /path/to/your/python`).  Then submit a [bug report](http://matplotlib.org/faq/troubleshooting_faq.html) to matplotlib, as suggested by @nneonneo.

Comment: Thanks for all the replies above. I am running the program under a Python virtual environment. I just exit and re-enter this environment. And it is working now. Any possible hint for this.

Comment: Are you using any extension modules that might have pointer bugs, corrupting memory?  The usual result of such situations are core dumps.  If you can reproduce the problem, the best solution is to either analyze a core dump with `gdb` or run Python under `gdb` to get a stack trace at the point of failure.   Another approach is to use `valgrind` to try catching pointer bugs.